# C# generate saml2 response can't get the response portion of the tags

Tags: c#, saml-2.0

So I'm trying to create a saml2 response using C# with .net 4.5 System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2Assertion class.

So far, I have created an assertion xml, but the sample I'm looking at here https://www.samltool.com/generic_sso_res.php has some response tags at the beginning. My first question is how do I get the response porition of that added to my assertion? (I'll post code below). My second question is that sample has tags like

Saml2NameIdentifier identifier = new Saml2NameIdentifier("myid.com");

```
    Saml2Assertion assert = new Saml2Assertion(identifier);
    assert.Subject = new Saml2Subject(identifier);

    string attrNamespace = "http://id.certmetrics.com/";

    Saml2AttributeStatement attrs = new Saml2AttributeStatement();

    DataRow row = qGetCanData.SqlExecDataTable(null, SelectedCandidate.CmcID).Rows[0];

    //we have a list of key value pairs in the json string that give us an attribute name, and a column name. The column
    //name is what value we would get from the data row using the eval string function
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> item in cset.Attributes)
    {
        string val = EvalString(row, item.Value, string.Empty);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(val))
        {
            Saml2Attribute attr = new Saml2Attribute(item.Key);
            attr.Values.Add(val);
            attrs.Attributes.Add(attr);
        }
    }

    assert.Statements.Add(attrs);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings() { OmitXmlDeclaration = true, Encoding = Encoding.UTF8 };

    // Use this line to get a .p12 file into the Hex format. Then copy/paste the Hex into a string to store it in the source code.
    //string sslCertBytesInHex = Utility.BytesToHex(File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath("~/app_data/ssl.p12")));

    string sslCertBytesInHex = "ABigLongHexHere";


    // This will load the cert just fine. By using "MachineKeySet", we avoid the need to use "Load User Profile"=true in the AppPool.
    X509Certificate2 clientCert = new X509Certificate2();
    clientCert.Import(Utility.HexToBytes(sslCertBytesInHex), "1234", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);

    X509SigningCredentials creds = new X509SigningCredentials(clientCert);

    assert.SigningCredentials = creds;

    Saml2SecurityToken token = new Saml2SecurityToken(assert);

    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    Saml2SecurityTokenHandler tokenHandler = new Saml2SecurityTokenHandler();
    tokenHandler.WriteToken(new XmlTextWriter(sw), token);

    //here is where I don't know how to get that "response" tags porition, plus add in the saml: to all the tags
```

The XML it generates looks like this

```
<Assertion ID="_6d1bd525-b460-42a7-9def-fe28d26f5713" IssueInstant="2017-06-14T12:54:28.141Z" Version="2.0" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
    <Issuer>myid.com</Issuer>
    <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <SignedInfo>
            <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
            <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
            <Reference URI="#_6d1bd525-b460-42a7-9def-fe28d26f5713">
                <Transforms>
                    <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
                    <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                </Transforms>
                <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
                <DigestValue>SomeString</DigestValue>
            </Reference>
        </SignedInfo>
        <SignatureValue>TheSigValue</SignatureValue>
        <KeyInfo>
            <X509Data>
                <X509Certificate>TheCertValue</X509Certificate>
            </X509Data>
        </KeyInfo>
    </Signature>
    <Subject>
        <NameID>myid.com</NameID>
    </Subject>
    <AttributeStatement>
        <Attribute Name="att1">
            <AttributeValue>att1</AttributeValue>
        </Attribute>
    </AttributeStatement>
</Assertion>
```

Answer (score 0):

The .NET Framework support for SAML2 is only for SAML2 Tokens - which is an `<Assertion>` in XML. To generate the `<Response>` XML you need something supporting the SAML2 Protocol. Either build it yourself or use an existing library. The one I've made that is open source is Kentor.AuthServices, but there are also other options both, open source and commercial.